# Notion of $4$-vectors in Lorentz symmetry violating case

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, definition, symmetry-breaking, action

[$4$-vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-vector) can be defined in various ways. One very common way among them is by saying if $A^{\mu}$ is some $4$-vector, then it will transform via the [Lorentz transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation) rule and will obey the relation: $A^{\mu}A_{\mu} = \text{constant}$.

Also there are some gravitational theories where the (spontaneous) Lorentz symmetry violation is considered in the action, like [Einstein--Bumblebee theory of gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bumblebee_models#:%7E:text=Bumblebee%20models%20are%20effective%20field,with%20spontaneous%20Lorentz%20symmetry%20breaking.), where the action takes the form

$\mathcal{A} = \displaystyle\int_{\mathcal{M}} d^Dx \sqrt{-g} \left[\dfrac{1}{2\kappa} R + \dfrac{\varrho}{2\kappa} B^\mu B^\nu R_{\mu\nu} - \dfrac{1}{4} B^{\mu\nu}B_{\mu\nu} - V\left(B^\mu B_\mu \mp b^2\right) + \mathcal{L}_{matter}\right]$

Here $B^\mu$ is the famous Bumblebee vector field and the Lorentz symmetry of the spacetime is spontaneously broken in presence of a non-zero vacuum expectation value of the field $\left(\left<B^\mu\right> = b^\mu; b^\mu b_\mu = b^2\right)$.

Now if one wants to define a $4$-vector in such a spacetime, then

1. First of all, how much relevant will it be to define a $4$-vector in such a gravity?
2. If it is equally relevant (as in Einstein's gravity), then what will be the corresponding definition of $4$-vector?
3. Will it still satisfy the relation $A^{\mu}A_{\mu} = \text{constant}$ for $A^\mu$ being any arbitrary $4$-vector?

Note, here $A^\mu$ may be the normal vector to the hypersurface in this spacetime manifold or can be the usual $4$-velocity vector or may be something else.